# Problema con fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo un pequeño form a manera de login, con las variables $user y $contrasena que tienen los valores correctos, el problema es que me da

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

es decir, como si el array estuviera vacío y no tengo idea por qué. Acá dejo el código (obviamente todo va encerrado en las etiquetas de php):

```
  include("conectarBD.php");

  $usuario = $_POST['user'];
  $contrasena = $_POST['pass'];

  if (isset($usuario) && !empty($usuario) && isset($contrasena) && !empty($contrasena)) {
    $sql = "SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario == :usuario";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array(':usuario'=>$usuario));
    $getUser = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $total = $getUser->rowCount();
    if ($total = 0) {
      echo "Nothing";
    }
}
```

Comment: El ""rowCount"" se usa en el statement `$total = $statement->rowCount();`, otra forma seria `$total =count($getUser);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De esta manera te va a funcionar `rowCount()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario";
                                          // No es == si no = ^^^ 
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute(array(':usuario'=>$usuario));

$getUser = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total = $statement->rowCount();

if ($total > 0) {
//        ^^^ no se compara con =
   echo "Hay cosas";

} else {

   echo "No hay nada";
}
```

Comment: Igual sigue sin guardarme nada, no sé que pasa

Comment: Es que es como que no traiga nada del formulario, porque el código sigue y lo demás lo tengo correcto, pero no viene nada del array, no sé por qué

Comment: Sí exactamente!! que como que está vacío

Comment: @Power_HR -  Haz probado una vez si tu sentencia devuelva algo? No se si usas phpMyAdmin o parecido, pero pruébalo en la consola directamente: `SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = 'nombre_de_usuario'`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias eres el p**o amo! :D no me había fijado en eso! buen ojo, gracias man, tu respuesta me ayudó demasiado

Comment: @Power_HR - De nada... a veces ven 4+ ojos más que 2

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a lo que vi en tu codigo es la siguiente:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario= :username AND contrasenia = :pass";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $contrasenia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        //obtenemos los resultados
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //Obtenemos el conteo de filas
        $filas = count($result);
        //Obtenemos el conteo de otra forma
        $filas = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Una de ls observaciones que vi en tu código, es que al hacer la comparacion usabas el operador **==** cuando no deberia ser eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! tienes toda la razón crack :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Devuelve un array asociativo (un mapa) común. No es un objeto, no contiene ningun método `rowCount()`. Para obtener la cantidad de datos que contiene un array o map, usa [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Creo que estás confundiendo con el método que ofrece el objeto [statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)
En tu caso, podrías invocarlo con

```
$statement->rowCount();
```

De todas maneras, [no se recomienda](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) usarlo para obtener la cantidad de filas que devuelve un SELECT:

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement
>   asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían
>   devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
>   este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
>   y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Comment: Igual sigue sin guardarme nada, no sé que pasa